# read udp [::]:4604: use of closed network connection

Tags: c#, go, server, udp

I am working on a UDP server. In the background, the server listens for `actions`, which are abstractions over packets sent by the clients:

```
    go func() {
        for {
            buf := make([]byte, 1024)
            n, addr, err := PC.ReadFrom(buf)
            ClientAddresses[addr] = struct{}{}
            action := &service.Action{}
            proto.Unmarshal(buf[:n], action)
            Actions.InsertAction(action)
        }
    }()
```

When the client sends a message, the server saves the address in a set, as shown below:

```
ClientAddresses[addr] = struct{}{}
```

Every 500 milliseconds the server processes every action sent by the clients and sends state changes to the clients by iterating over the address set:

```
        for Changes.Len() > 0 {
            LogWhiteText("Sending state change:")
            LogPurpleText(Changes.GetChange())
            change := Changes.GetChange()
            for addr, _ := range ClientAddresses {
                SendChange(change, PC, addr)
            }
            Changes.RemoveChange()
        }
```

```
// SendChange sends an individual state change to a client
func SendChange(change *service.Change, pc net.PacketConn, addr net.Addr) {
    packet, err := proto.Marshal(change)
    if err != nil {
        LogRedText(err)
        return
    }
    pc.WriteTo(packet, addr)
}
```

Right after the server starts and the first client connects, the following error is triggered:

```
2020/10/10 01:39:48  Send state changes to the clients
2020/10/10 01:39:48  Sending state change:
2020/10/10 01:39:48  locationChange:{coordinate:{lng:12.476284  lat:41.91051}}
2020/10/10 01:39:48  read udp [::]:4604: use of closed network connection
panic: assignment to entry in nil map
```

I would like to get some suggestions on the error cause. As the error suggests, the connection is closed but I don't close it from the side of the client:

```
private UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();

    void onStart()
    {

        locationManager.onLocationChanged.AddListener(this.SendChangedLocation);
        try
        {
            udpClient.Connect("localhost", 4604);
            Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate
            {
                Lng = (float)locationManager.currentLocation.longitude,
                Lat = (float)locationManager.currentLocation.latitude,
            };
            this.CreateNewCar(coordinate);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.LogError(exc);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The client code is either closing the connection or the application is terminating (which also will close the connection).  The issue is not with the code posted.  The issue is in the code that calls the onStart method.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for your help. Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the client.